# Convert table rows into columns in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, pivot-table, transpose

This is my table :

| ID | Parameter | Reading |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1213 | Sr No. | 1 |
| 1213 | Sr No. | (null) |
| 1213 | Sr No. | (null) |
| 1213 | Name | (null) |
| 1213 | Name | Final Rating |
| 1213 | Name | Majority Rating |
| 1214 | Sr No. | 1 |
| 1214 | Sr No. | (null) |
| 1214 | Sr No. | (null) |
| 1214 | Name | (null) |
| 1214 | Name | Final Rating |
| 1214 | Name | Majority Rating |

I want output as:

| ID | Sr No. | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1213 | 1 | (null) |
| 1213 | (null) | Final Rating |
| 1213 | (null) | Majority Rating |

I want to do this in Microsoft SQL Server.

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Reading FROM test_table 
     WHERE ID = 1213 AND Parameter = 'Sr No.') AS SrNo,
    (SELECT Reading FROM test_table 
     WHERE ID = 1213 AND Parameter = 'Name') AS Name
FROM 
    test_table
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Firstly, having a table colunm called Parameter might not be a good idea and in your Output, the column name has changed to "Sr No." which seems to be data.
Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: With the data you have, it's impossible; you have no way to identify what rows are related to the others. How to you know what name relates to what SR No? Why is it not `'(null)','(null)'` or `'1','Final Rating'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Parameter VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
  ,Reading   VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable
(ID,Parameter,Reading) VALUES 
(1213,'Sr No.','1'),
(1213,'Sr No.','(null)'),
(1213,'Sr No.','(null)'),
(1213,'Name','(null)'),
(1213,'Name','Final Rating'),
(1213,'Name','Majority Rating'),
(1214,'Sr No.','1'),
(1214,'Sr No.','(null)'),
(1214,'Sr No.','(null)'),
(1214,'Name','(null)'),
(1214,'Name','Final Rating'),
(1214,'Name','Majority Rating');
```

use `Row_number` and `Join` in your `Subquery` to get your desired result

```
SELECT A.id,
       [sr no.],
       [name]
FROM   (SELECT id,
               reading         AS 'Sr No.',
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  parameter = 'Sr No.') A,
       (SELECT id,
               reading         AS 'Name',
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  parameter = 'Name') B
WHERE  A.id = B.id
       AND A.rn = B.rn
       AND A.id = 1213
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f643887763cc53816d8f5898f423cd1c)